# Test::Builder::Tester fail test failing, why?

Tags: perl, testing

Here's there output of the test.

```
prove -lv t/02-fail.t
t/02-fail.t .. 
not ok 1
1..1

#   Failed test at t/02-fail.t line 15.
# STDOUT is:
# ok 1 - corpus/fail/FooBar.pm version 1.0.1 is valid
# not ok 2 - corpus/fail/FooBarBaz.pm version  is valid
# 
# not:
# ok 1 - corpus/fail/FooBar.pm version 1.0.1 is valid
# 
# not ok 2 - corpus/fail/FooBarBaz.pm version  is valid
# 
# as expected
# STDERR is:
# #   Failed test 'corpus/fail/FooBarBaz.pm version  is valid'
# #   at /home/xenoterracide/projects/Test-HasValidVersion/lib/Test/HasValidVersion.pm line 60.
# # corpus/fail/FooBarBaz.pm VERSION  is not a valid verion
# 
# not:
# 
# as expected
Failed 1/1 subtests 

Test Summary Report
-------------------
t/02-fail.t (Wstat: 0 Tests: 1 Failed: 1)
  Failed test:  1
Files=1, Tests=1,  0 wallclock secs ( 0.02 usr  0.01 sys +  0.04 cusr  0.01 csys =  0.08 CPU)
Result: FAIL
```

and the test itself

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use 5.006;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Test::Builder::Tester;
use Test::More;
use Test::HasValidVersion qw( version_all_ok );

test_out( 'ok 1 - corpus/fail/FooBar.pm version 1.0.1 is valid',
    'not ok 2 - corpus/fail/FooBarBaz.pm version  is valid'
);

version_all_ok( 'corpus/fail' );

test_test;
done_testing;
```

*( note: here's a link to the [github repository](https://github.com/xenoterracide/Test-Version/tree/daaab6a7c452958399f74150406915657f2cfa33) the test code there is a little different but fails about the same. module isn't any different. If you clone the repo make sure you check out commit daaab6a7c452958399f74150406915657f2cfa33 as the master branch is updating )*

I'm not sure why this is failing, it seems to be injecting a whole line that the [docs](http://perldoc.perl.org/Test/Builder/Tester.html) don't mention.

Can someone help me correct the code to make it pass?

Comment: Maybe you could email the author. Failing that, could you use Test::Tester instead?

Comment: @snoopy I am the author... unless you mean the author of Test::Builder::Tester

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I needed to do was add a `test_fail(+4)` into the code. Ultimately I switched to [`Test::Tester`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Test-Tester/lib/Test/Tester.pm) to not have to deal with whitespace issues.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use 5.006;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Test::Builder::Tester;
use Test::More;
use Test::HasValidVersion qw( version_ok );

test_out(
    'ok 1 - VERSION 1.0.1 in corpus/fail/FooBar.pm is valid',
    'not ok 2 - validate VERSION in corpus/fail/FooBarBaz.pm',
);
test_fail(+4);
test_diag('VERSION in corpus/fail/FooBarBaz.pm is not a valid version');

version_ok( 'corpus/fail/FooBar.pm' );
version_ok( 'corpus/fail/FooBarBaz.pm' );
# version_all_ok('corpus/fail');

test_test;
done_testing;
```

Here's a [link to the fixed commit](https://github.com/xenoterracide/Test-Version/blob/da54d2c2bf96adcccb07e3430e0de70e63e4aa43/t/02-fail.t)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried upgrading Test::More and Test::Builder::Tester to the most recent versions? With perl-5.10.1 and perl-5.14.0-RC3 here and the most recent version of both, I can't replicate your error, using a checkout of your git repo (and fixing the obvious problem with the lines in the repo being reversed).

Comment: I'm running 5.12.3 and whatever latest Test::More is, mike doherty helped me figure it out. I'll posted an answer later. obviously if you're not using the commit I linked it will now pass because it's been fixed in master.